# scope $watch causing infinite digest loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope, angularjs-scope

In a directive I need to watch the formData to check if it is valid so I can enable the submit button. I've added an attribute to the directive in the view which I've added to the directives isolated scope which contains the formData. I'm using `scope.$watch('questionData', function() {}, true)` and the value `true` as a third parameter as has been advised to me like so:

```
//VIEW

<question-panel>
    <form name="grantForm" method="get" novalidate>
        <questionnaire-submit-button 
         service="'grantquestions/grant'" 
         question-data="grantForm">
       </questionnaire-submit-button>
    </form>
</question-panel>

//DIRECTIVE

angular.module('ppApp').directive('questionnaireSubmitButton', questionnaireSubmitButton);

questionnaireSubmitButton.$inject = [];

function questionnaireSubmitButton() {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            service: '@',
            questionData: '='
        },
        template: '<div data-ng-include="templateUrl"></div>',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            scope.templateUrl = 'app/templates/directives/' + scope.service.replace(/'/g,'') + '-submit.button.tpl.htm';

            scope.$watch('questionData', function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
                console.log(newValue, oldValue)
            }, true); //Infinite loop occurs with this scope.watch
        

        }
    }

}
```

However this is resulting in an infinite digest loop. If I remove the true, it registers on initiation but does not seem to watch for any change to the form input felds.

I'm receving these errors:

> Can't copy! Making copies of Window or Scope instances is not supported.
>
> 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
> Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []

***Question***

How do I watch for any changes in the form from the directive without causing an infinite loop? I'm trying to check if it is valid or not.

Comment: you could use $scope.$on (from this directve) and $rootScope.$broadcast (from the form directive) at each ng-change of any input, and stop watching recursively (in this directive).

Comment: Normally submit buttons are enabled by watching the [`$valid`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$valid) property of the [ngFormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController).

Comment: You might be able to look into the ui-validate async validation and apply that to each of your inputs, and then do what george suggests and use a straight up disable on $invalid/$valid.  It would move your validation from the submit button to the controller.  You'd have to add the ui-validate to each ng-model but you'd be making the same number of network calls and handling the submit enabled in almost the same way.